# define gulp file for pdf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pdf.js

I'm following the steps in [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) and I'm having problems with defining the gulp file. I defined it as in [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#getting-started) so like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});
```

but when I run `$ gulp server` in nodejs I got

```
[14:48:12] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\pdfSearch2\gulpfile.js
[14:48:12] Task 'server' is not in your gulpfile
[14:48:12] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

Presumably I need to define 'server' too, but how do I do that, as the guide doesn't say anything about that (sorry new to nodejs!)
thanks

Comment: Your links are not working. Gulp is not working because you have't defined task server. Try gulp default. Then it should work.

Comment: Apologies for the links, they work now. Yes if I run `gulp default` it works, but the guide says that I need to start up a server with gulp server. So should I modify my file and add something like `gulp.task('server', function() {});` so that I can then browse to `http://localhost:8888/web/viewer.html` What else should go in it to start a server?

Comment: Well this is how can you test library itself. So you need to clone repo firstly.

Here you can find source code of server task:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L564

I think this is not tutorial for how to use pdf.js in your application

Comment: For tutorial how to use pdf.js, I think you should look at this link: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-pdf.js-in-a-website

Comment: I sorted out the problems, now the library works in that I can run it on http://localhost:8888/web/viewer.html as the guide says. So if I want to use my own script now, say, extend the functionality or write my own I just create my own script and, for example, loop through the text and get out what I want? Like, your link starts with the script http://pastebin.com/pELHPahF which I could incorporate in mine?

Comment: I would say so. From their documentatio I would say this is the way you could include their library into your application.

Comment: cool, the only thing is, the guide says to start off by installing pdfjs-dist and when I do that, in the root folder of my application, I get some warnings and errors related to the enoent file, see here http://pastebin.com/JF543tqe. Do I have to run that command inside the library folder or the root folder of my application?

Comment: I would say that you don't have package.json file. If that is the case run first npm init in your project. I would advise you to introduce yourself a little bit with npm and gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Well links that you have supplied show how you can test library itself. So you need to clone repo firstly and then run

> gulp server

task. [Here](http://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L564) you can find source code of server task. I think this is not tutorial for how to use pdf.js in your application and that this is not what you need!

For tutorial how to use pdf.js, I think you should look at this [link](http://For%20tutorial%20how%20to%20use%20pdf.js,%20I%20think%20you%20should%20look%20at%20this%20link).